# Woocommerce how to use jquery to get a value inside "cart-subtotal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

This question has been put but I need something different and I don't know if it's even possible.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
  <th>Subtotal</th>
  <td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>713.99</bdi></span></td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the `713.99`.

How can I do it? I know I can get it from inside the bdi:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var str = $('bdi').clone().find('span').remove().end().text().split('"')[1]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

But how do I do if from specifically class="cart-subtotal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not efficient but working for your case.

```
var re = /(\d+\.\d+)/.exec($(".woocommerce-Price-amount").html());
```

then you can reach it by taking the first element which is re[0]

Comment: It needs to reffer to 'cart-subtotal' , If I do it like this it will just take the first 'woocommerce-Price-amount' witch is not the one i need.